# 'No input file specified' - Laravel Homestead

Tags: laravel-5, homestead

I'm having this message when trying to access to my app in Laravel 5. I have been trying to solve it following different ideas I have seen in this forum and others. It seems like is a problem in my Homestead.yaml file, but I cannot find where my error is. That is what I have in my Homestead.yaml:

> folders:
>       - map: ~/Code
>         to: /home/vagrant/Code
>
> sites:
>       - map: testing1.app
>         to: /home/vagrant/Code/testing1/public

I also added this line to my 'hosts':

> 192.168.10.10 testing1.app

Any idea what could I do?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

At First, please make sure your local directory is: `Code` which is in `/home`, where you will keep all of your Laravel app and it's mapping to VM's directory `/home/vagrant/Code`

Now, make sure your Laravel app inside `testing1` and it's inside `Code`directory.

Now command: `vagrant reload --provision`

During configure Homestead.yaml never use `tab` key for space, instead use `spacebar`

Finally, Please let me know which OS you are using?